# Can there be minimal dense subalgebra for Banach algebra?

Tags: functional-analysis

Consider a Banach algebra $A$, can there be minimal dense subalgebra? i.e a subalgebra which is dense and it only contain itself and zero as algebra.

I am thinking this thing might exists because for finite dimension it is trivial. However for infinite dimension I am not sure.